# In CheckBoxTreeViewer, how to stop checking/unchecking items from also selecting them?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using JFace's CheckBoxTreeViewer.

When a user clicks on the text of an item, it becomes selected in the tree and elsewhere in presentations of the same document. This is desired behavior.

When a user just clicks on the checkbox, the tree item is also becoming selected, at least in Windows and Mac implementations. Because of the desired behavior above, that in turn leads to the current selection being replaced.

I would like the user to be able to turn on/off items in the tree without replacing the current selection. Is there a way to configure the CheckBoxTreeViewer so that checking/unchecking does not also select the tree item? Or is that behavior just part of the OS-specific look-and-feel?

Comment: In Windows 10, using [this example program](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesCheckboxTreeViewer.htm) (and adding the style `SWT.MULTI`), clicking on a checkbox does not select the item and the previous selections are preserved. Do you have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the behavior you described?

Comment: @LorisSecuro - I've tried that example, and get the behavior you describe, even without adding SWT.MULTI. Thank you for an extremely helpful observation. Your example suffices. Now I can look into what's different between the example and our case. One difference is that I'm running in RCP. Not sure if that matters yet. Thanks!

Comment: @LorisSecuro - Thank you. Your observation led me to the two problems in my code that led to the observed behavior differing from the default. I've posted that as an answer since one of the issues may affect others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I was seeing was not the default or native behavior. Thanks to @LorisSecuro's comment and example for making this clear.

I found and fixed two problems.

The first was my fault. In the `ICheckStateListener`, I had missed some code that ... set the selection.

The second problem was something that others might run into. CheckboxTreeViewer was calling my `ISelectionChangedListener` whenever someone checked/unchecked an item -- **even if the selection had not changed**. I presumed the selection had changed, given that my ISelectionChangedListener had been called, and set the selection outside the tree.

```
MySelectionChangedListener.selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event)
...
CheckboxTreeViewer(Viewer).fireSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent) line: 160    
CheckboxTreeViewer(StructuredViewer).updateSelection(ISelection) line: 2197 
CheckboxTreeViewer(StructuredViewer).handleSelect(SelectionEvent) line: 1228    
CheckboxTreeViewer.handleSelect(SelectionEvent) line: 291   
StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(SelectionEvent) line: 1257    
OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(SelectionEvent) line: 242   
...
```

The solution was simple. I keep track of the selection, and verify that it has actually changed before doing anything in the ISelectionChangedListener.

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
  ITreeSelection treeSelection = m_treeViewer.getStructuredSelection();
  List<?> newSelection = treeSelection.toList();

  if ( ! m_lastKnownSelection.equals( newSelection )) {
    ...
    m_lastKnownSelection = newSelection;
  }
}
```